# Breeze.js and Entity Framework - How do I expose xref table when generating an EDMX from the DB?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, breeze

Breeze.js doesn't handle many to manys, so I need to spell out the 1 to many with xref tables. But how do I force EF to expose those xrefs when generating my EDMX from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The EDM designer will include the join table as an entity in the model if it includes "payload", that is, additional columns other than the PK.  This post is old, but still seems to have the best description of how to do this:  http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a lot of existing code that depends on concealed xrefs. So I'm generating a new DbContext which exposes the xrefs for Breeze. Presently, I'm trying to use the Reverse Engineer Code-First tool to expose the xrefs -- via the T4 templates. But no dice thus far.